# Browserify does not resolve external file

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to use `browserify` inside `gulp`. The `Gulpfile.js` contains the simple task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
var x = browserify('./src/main/js/init.js');
return x.bundle({
    ignoreMissing: true
})
    .pipe(source('init.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));

});
```

Where `init.js` is:

```
require("d3");
```

I'm trying to use the alias `"d3"` which is an external dependency which `browserify` should not try to resolve. Running this causes `browserify` to hang, despite it saying the task has. How is the best way to go about this? Using `browserify 4.2.0`.

PS: Have also tried to use the `external` option

EDIT: running it from the command line

```
browserify src/main/js/init.js  --ignore-missing
```

Seems to work

Comment: What do you mean "`"d3"` which is defined in a different task."? Do you mean in a different bundle? What does "causes `browserify` to hang" mean? "despite it saying the task has"...what? Completed? "PS: Have also tried to use the external option" -- and what happened?

Comment: Just that it is an external dependency which browserify shouldn't try to resolve (edited question to better explain this). Browserify says the task has finished, but freezes the shell and doesn't output any file. Same for the external option.

Comment: What version of browserify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

```js
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  return browserify('./src/main/js/init.js')
    .exclude('d3')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('init.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
});
```

Comment: The exclude option is what I was missing, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gulp.src` on the entry file 
I use this and it works

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
browserify = require('gulp-browserify');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {

   return gulp.src('./src/main/js/init.js')
        .pipe(browserify({ //browserify options
            debug: true
        }))
        .pipe(rename('initBuild.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
}
```

---

**Edit**

Obviously it's deprecated.
Try to use object options on the browserify constructor.

```
var x = browserify({
    entries: './src/main/js/init.js',
    ignoreMissing: true
});

return x.bundle()
    .pipe(source('init.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
```

Comment: Not using `gulp-browserify` as it is deprecated.https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify